# How many certified project managers in the world?

Tags: pmp, certification, prince2

ISTR that it is estimated that there are over 1 million project managers with the PRINCE2 certification, but can someone point me to an accurate reference for this and/or any other certifications such as PMP?

Thanks.
Peter

Comment: Hi & welcome to PMSE. Have a look on the [tour] page to understand how this site works. Due to the fact, that it looks like a "search-engine-question", your question might be closed as off topic. Try to re-phrase your question in order to highlight the real world PM problem.

Comment: http://www.bestpractices-pmptraining.com/pmi-announces-major-milestone-500000-pmps-worldwide/

Answer (score 5):

PMI publishes "PMI Today", which displays the number of Active certification holders.  As of August 2015 there are 655,576 PMPs, and 28,826 CAPMs. Another up-and-coming certification is the Agile Certified practitioner PMI-ACP which has 8,870.  The other 5 certification streams have less than 4k.

All told a little under 700k.  Keep in mind that some people may hold multiple certifications, and there are other organizations who do PM certs too.

Answer (score -1):

[image]

These graphics are often found at the beginning of PM Network, a magazine put out by the Project Management Institute.

Comment: While the graphic is relevant, image-only answers with “filler” text is considered low quality. You could replace your filler with a source and a brief explanation to avoid downvotes.